# I'm having a problem with parsed_response when I use class httparty

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bdd

[image]
I'm have a problem with class `httparty`

```
 class CRUD

       include HTTParty

       def self.create   

      @base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
        @body = 
        {
        "user": {
        "email": Faker::Internet.email,
        "password": :@password,
        "password_confirmation": :@password
         }    
    }.to_json

    @headers = {
                 "Accept": 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }   

      @request = HTTParty.post(@base_url, body: @body, headers: @headers)
          end 
      end
```

My step_definitions

```
When("é enviada uma requisição para a criação do usuário") do
   CRUD.create
    puts "Requisição com exito: #{CRUD.create.message} para código #{CRUD.create.code}" 
 end

then("são retornadas as informações da inclusão") do
   puts CRUD.create.body
   puts CRUD(@request.parsed_response['data']['attributes']['email'])
 end
```

Comment: Why don't you assign a var to the result of `CRUD.create`? Then try calling `parsed_response` on that

Comment: The real issue is that the instance vars you define in your method call aren't available in your tests. It's a different context.

Comment: It seems like you need to read up on classes, instances, and instance variables. You’re doing a lot of things that don’t make sense. For example, you don’t have access to `@request` outside of `CRUD`. While you can use instance variables in class methods, the way you’re using them isn’t benefiting you at all, and is not thread safe. And calling `create` over and over is inefficient, as it would perform your web request every time you do it — you should be caching the result. Your problems run much deeper than HTTParty.

Comment: OK Nate, if you want to teach me how you do instead of criticizing me I accept and thank you.

Comment: See that, i can to made that and make a sense!!    .  puts CRUD.class_variable_get(:@@request).parsed_response['data']['attributes']['email']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[OK, I made the adjustments and the test ran, but I have a problem now !. Why is the query email (get)is different from the inclusion email (post)?

see my class

require 'HTTParty'
require 'httparty/request'
require 'httparty/response/headers'

#require_relative '..features/pages/hooks/hook.rb'

class CRUD

   include HTTParty

   def create  

  @base_url  = 'https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/users'
    @body = 
    {
    "user": {
    "email": Faker::Internet.email,
    "password":  :@password,
    "password_confirmation": :@password

     }    
}.to_json

@headers = {
             "Accept": 'application/vnd.tasksmanager.v2',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}   

  @request = CRUD.post(@base_url, body: @body, headers: @headers)
 end

  def retrieve
    @response  = CRUD.get('https://api-de-tarefas.herokuapp.com/contacts') 
 end 
end


See my step_definitions

Dado("que eu tenha um payload padrão") do
  @manter_user = CRUD.new
 end

Quando("é enviada uma requisição para a criação do usuário") do
   @manter_user.create
    puts "Requisição com exito: #{@manter_user.create.message} para código #{@manter_user.create.code}" 
 end

Então("são retornadas as informações da inclusão") do
   puts @manter_user.create.body
   puts @manter_user.create.parsed_response\['data'\]\['attributes'\]\['email'\] 
 end

  Dado("que eu tenha o usuário cadastrado") do 
    @manter_user = CRUD.new                                       
    @manter_user.create
    puts @manter_user.create.body

  end                                                                                 

  Quando("é enviada uma requisição de consulta") do                                   
    @manter_user.retrieve
    puts "Consulta processada com sucesso #{@manter_user.retrieve.code}"
  end                                                                                

  Então("a API me retorna a informação do usuário") do                                
    puts @manter_user.create.parsed_response\['data'\]\['attributes'\]\['email'\] 
  end][1]  

enter code here
```